# passing class to a formula produces the same value

Tags: c#

In my code below I have output which shows different values for ema12 (the methods only calculate the ema12 value but in the list of classes, each class has the same value for the last ema12 value in the list even though each one is different and somehow all ema12 values are now the same. Am I missing something simple?

```
CalculationData currentCalcData = new CalculationData();

for (int i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++)
{
    var currentDate = Data.ElementAt(i).Date;

    currentCalcData = PassValuesToCalculationData(ListCalculationData, currentCalcData, 
        i, days, currentDate, PassIndicatorType.ExponentialMovingAverage);
    currentCalcData = PassValuesToCalculationData(ListCalculationData, currentCalcData, 
        i, days, currentDate, PassIndicatorType.SimpleMovingAverage);

    Console.WriteLine(currentCalcData.Ema12);

    // add current calculator class to the list
    ListCalculationData.Add(currentCalcData);
}
```

Output via Console.WriteLine():

```
47.614134621466156130843047529
47.832250005270668646730641192
47.832250005270668646730641192
48.050616671234579493833222366
48.050616671234579493833222366
48.137201115069968894655459384
48.137201115069968894655459384
48.173574299727306375368064800
48.173574299727306375368064800
48.237097726430332191985656160
48.237097726430332191985656160
48.292151362906287899720902005
48.292151362906287899720902005
48.331864514518782846424781738
48.331864514518782846424781738
48.407615912582945133568144173
48.407615912582945133568144173
48.441267124238552449092391617
48.441267124238552449092391617
48.491764841006745455880072735
```

Values for ema12 in each class in the list is: `48.49`

This is the method that it calls in the PassValuesToCalculationData

```
case PassIndicatorType.MovingAverageConvergenceDivergenceOscillator:
// for ema 12
    if (index >= 11)
    {
        if (index == 11)
        {
            // get sma to start ema
            currentCalcData.Ema12 = CalculateSMA(12, currentDate, SmaType.Price);
        }
        else
        {
            // get regular ema
            currentCalcData.Ema12 = CalculateEMA(smoothingFactor, currentPrice, listCalcData.ElementAt(index - 1).Ema12);

        // for ema 26
        if (index >= 25)
        {
            if (index == 25)
            {
                // get sma to start ema
                currentCalcData.Ema26 = CalculateSMA(26, currentDate, SmaType.Price);
            }
            else
            {
                // get regular ema
                currentCalcData.Ema26 = CalculateEMA(smoothingFactor, currentPrice, listCalcData.ElementAt(index - 1).Ema26);

                // get macd line and other macd stuff
                currentCalcData.Macd = CalculateMACDLine(currentCalcData.Ema12, currentCalcData.Ema26);

                // add macd to list to get ema of macd
                currentCalcData.ListMacd.Add(currentCalcData.Macd);

                // macd signal line is 9 day ema of macd
                if (currentCalcData.ListMacd.Count >= 9)
                {
                    if (currentCalcData.ListMacd.Count == 9)
                    {
                        // do sma to start ema
                        currentCalcData.MacdSignal = currentCalcData.ListMacd.Average();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentCalcData.MacdSignal = CalculateEMA(smoothingFactor, currentCalcData.MacdSignal, listCalcData.ElementAt(index - 1).MacdSignal);
                        currentCalcData.MacdHistogram = CalculateMACDHistogram(currentCalcData.Macd, currentCalcData.MacdSignal);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
break;
```

Comment: Where does that opening parenthesis closes in your post - `(the methods only calculate `. Its absence is making the post hard to understand.

Comment: Are you using some kind of library we should know? Otherwise, I'd say it depends on what the `PassValuesToCalculationData` method does.

Comment: @vesan No I'm not using any third party library. I just updated to show an example of what the PassValuesToCalculationData method does

Comment: @RBT I edited my post to make it easier to understand I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is because you only instantiate 1 object currentCalcData and put that same reference into the ListCalculationData multiple times.

The solution is put the currentCalcData instantiation inside the for loop, then you will have different objects inside the ListCalculationData.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++)
{
    CalculationData currentCalcData = new CalculationData();
    var currentDate = Data.ElementAt(i).Date;
    //.... and continue the rest
```

Comment: I posted the details for the method above but I can't do the instantiation inside the loop because my code needs to access the list in the class and it adds to the list in each iteration of the loop

Comment: Do you have copy constructor? Before you add it into the list, make a copy of it as new instance. `CalculationData calcDataToTheList = new CalculationData(currentCalcData); ListCalculationData.Add(calcDataToTheList);`

Comment: It's exactly like @kurakura88 says. Perhaps your list should only contain the result value you're interested in, not the whole `CalculationData` class?

Comment: @vesan I was only including the ema12 value for this question but that class has at least 40 other values that it needs so that is why I chose to put it all in a class

Comment: @kurakura88 What good will it do to make a copy of everything to add to the list? Won't that just do the same thing it is doing now?

Comment: No. Like I mentioned already, currentCalcData is a reference to an object that you instantiated earlier. When you add that same reference to the list, it will always point to the same object. Sure the value is changing over time, but it is still the same reference to the same object. Copying it to different object means that you have a different reference to different object. Since we are making a copy each loop, it will be multiple different references(each to different object).